# From what material and how are the Merlin engines and nozzles of it (sea level) manufactured?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engines, materials, merlin-1d

I am specifically interested in the alloy used to build the engine, also about the nozzle: Is it just in one piece or welded using different sections. If they are welded then which welding techniques are used to withstand such high temperatures, re-entry, etc.

**NOTE**: I am only asking about the sea-level engines as there are a lot of questions already been asked and answered briefly in this platform regarding the vacuum engine.

Comment: +1 Following this question. Please link to the questions "regarding the vacuum" variant that you mention, however.

Comment: I have edited the title. I am asking about both- the nozzle and the engine

Comment: This most likely is both ITAR restricted and a SpaceX trade secret. You might not get a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

Tl;Dr; Nickel-cobalt with a copper cooling jacket.

[Spacenews](https://spacenews.com/elon-musk-chief-executive-and-chief-technology-officer-space-exploration-technologies/#:~:text=The%20hardest%20part%20of%20the,can%20make%20a%20metal%20thing.) interviewed Elon Musk where he said

> "....
>   The hardest part of the engine to mass produce is the electro-plating of nickel cobalt on the chamber. We create this thick metal jacket that takes the primary stress of the pressure vessel and it’s plated one molecule at a time. Plating is about the slowest way you can make a metal thing. With the Merlin-1D we take a metal jacket that is explosively formed. We take a metal sheet that’s in a cylindrical form and put it in a bucket of water, effectively. Sort of a concrete pool. And you set off an explosive and the jacket just goes “boohmp” and forms to the outer side walls into a jacket shape, so you have a mold, effectively. And then you just put the jacket on the chamber and braise it on. You can do several a day. We have a fully integrated engine and it’s being test-fired right now. There’s really not a lot of question marks remaining about the Merlin-1D.
>   ..."

You can also check out this blog with excellent images of Merlin production from 2006.
https://selenianboondocks.com/2006/10/spacex-comstac-briefing/

Comment: `+1` apparently rumors of this [being a secret](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44628/from-what-material-and-how-are-the-merlin-engines-and-nozzles-of-it-sea-level#comment144354_44628) have been [greatly exaggerated](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Mark-Twain-say-The-rumours-of-my-death-have-been-greatly-exaggerated)!

Comment: How do you mass-produce an engine so that it doesn't blow up? By blowing it up, apparently!

Comment: Blast-forming has been used for manufacturing tank bulkheads since at least the Apollo era. Has it been used for combustion chambers before the Merlin?